# Return type same as input type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, union-types

I have two functions that do the same thing with the only difference that the input types and return types are different. I was wondering how I could "merge" these functions into one and one of the ideas was to use a union type but my constrain is that when the input is one member of the union the returned value has to be the same.

```
const getViewStyle = (styles: ViewStyle[]): ViewStyle => {
  return Object.assign({}, ...styles);
};

const getTextStyle = (styles: TextStyle[]): TextStyle => {
  return Object.assign({}, ...styles);
};
```

Comment: Use generic type, it allows you to set any income/outcome parameters.

Comment: Or you can use `:any` type if you dont care about concrete type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has worked for me. All credit goes to Marius Schulz - https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2016/08/18/function-overloads-in-typescript#version-4-function-overloads

```
function getStyle(styles: ViewStyle[]): ViewStyle;
function getStyle(styles: TextStyle[]): TextStyle;
function getStyle(styles: ViewStyle[] | TextStyle[]): ViewStyle | TextStyle {
    return Object.assign({}, ...styles);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can do this:

```
const flattenObjectsToSingle = <T>(items: T[]): T => { ...
```

Comment: The thing is that I care about the type, I don't want it to be generic. I want to make sure the function gets passed an array of one or the either type and returns the same type.

Comment: @NickDima Could `T extends ViewStyle | TextStyle` work?

Comment: What is the syntax for a `function () {}` declaration?

Comment: Could we have a link to the typescript documentation please?

Answer (score 8):

A mix of generics and inferred types would be the best. The accepted answer would let the linter of typescript keep complaining if you expect one of the types to be returned when you are using the function.

So, in my opinion, this would be the best answer:

```
const getStyle = <T extends TextStyle | ViewStyle >(styles: T[]): T => { 
      return Object.assign({}, ...styles);
};
```

What this basicly say is that The function expect an array of TextStyle or ViewStyle and return one record of what ever type is given.

Credit goes to Ben Awad video on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nViEqpgwxHE

Comment: But this doesn't actually work for me for some reason.
The 'function overloads' is what I had to do in order for this to work. Even if it is quite verbose.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly....

```
const getStyle = (styles: TextStyle[] | ViewStyle[]): TextStyle | ViewStyle[] => {
  return Object.assign({}, ...styles);
};
```

see http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html for more cool stuff

Comment: I think you have the return type wrong. Should't it be `TextStyle | ViewStyle` instead of `TextStyle | ViewStyle[]`?

Comment: But what happens if I call the function with TextStyle[] and return ViewStyle? I don't want to allow that...