# TypeScript - Define return type as input type

Tags: typescript, generics

So, to simplify things, suppose I've got a method as follows

```
sum(o: Point | Vector): Point | Vector {
  if (o instanceof Point) {
    return new Point(o.x + this.x, o.y + this.y, o.z + this.z)
  }
  if (o instanceof Vector) {
    return new Vector(o.x + this.x, o.y + this.y, o.z + this.z)
  }
}
```

As you can see, the actual logic is the exact same thing which makes it a bit silly to have to duplicate it. When invoking the method and passing it, for example, a `Point` object, the return type is not correctly derived. I have to do an explicit cast to `Point`.

I could use generic typing and declare the parameter as `T` but then it won't recognize the `x`, `y` and `z` variables of course.

My questions is a bit like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49564509/return-type-same-as-input-type-in-typescript) one but with the difference my types are not arrays and that the question doesn't have an answer.

Can this be solved somewhat more beautifully in TypeScript?

Comment: How about an interface?

Comment: Yeah, that would be my last option. That, or duplicating the method with a slightly different name. It's just that dedicating an interface to hold those three variables seems like an overkill :)

Comment: `sum` is a method of -- what? `Point`? `Vector`?

Comment: @OscarPaz Of another class even.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the constructor with generic constraint explicitly.

```
function sum<T extends Point | Vector>(c: new (a: number, b: number,c: number) => T, o: T): (T) {  
  return new c(o.x + this.x, o.y +  this.y, o.z + this.z); 
}

let t = x.sum(Point, new Point(1, 2, 3));
```

Comment: You could slightly change a constraint: `T extends (Point | Vector) & { constructor: any }` and get constructor from the instance: `new o.constructor(o.x ...`

Comment: I like this solution as it does not depend on extra types that need to be defined. Especially with the addition of @AlekseyL., things can be kept concise.

Comment: @Aleksey L. yeah i actually tried giving constructor info in constraints but i could not figure out the syntax to specify the arguments' types with something like `(Point | Vector) & { constructor: (a:number ... )}`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a generic type with a restriction, like:

```
export abstract class SumableClass {

    public sum<T extends SumableClass >(o: T): T {
        return o.constructor(o.x + this.x, o.y + this.y, o.z + this.z);
    }

    constructor(public x: number, public y: number, public z: number) {

    }
}
```

Also defined an abstract (SumableClass), Point and Vector should inherited from it

Comment: This is another solution that would fit my needs, even though it requires an additional interface.

Comment: just realized that the interface is unneccessary :) I will update the code